# Core Data NSPredicate fetch objects with NSDate attribute that fall into an arbitrary day or date range

Tags: core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm asking for help with a specific core data predicate (if that is at all possible to handle this with a single fetch).

I have a couple of objects that have a .date property (NSDate). On average, there are about 4-20 objects for a particular day. Think of journal entries if you will.

```
[Journal]
-date: NSDate
```

e.g.:

J1: ["date": "2015-08-10 9:00"],

J2: ["date": "2015-08-10 14:00"],

J3: ["date": "2015-08-10 18:00"],

J4: ["date": "2015-08-09 9:00"],

J5: ["date": "2015-08-09 13:00"],

...

I'd like to perform several fetches based on the date of the last entry (not knowing when that actually was):

1: fetch all journal entries that took place in the last day.

2: fetch all journal entries that happened in the last week

3: fetch all journal entries that happened in the last month

I'm using an async fetch request to fetch the objects:

```
context.performBlock() {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Journal")
            fetchRequest.predicate = self.page?.predicate

            let asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest) { (result) in
                if result.finalResult?.count > 0 {
                    println("we are done with our async fetch")

                }

                completion?(result.finalResult as? [Journal])
            }

            var fetchError: NSError?
            let fetchResult = context.executeRequest(asyncFetchRequest, error: &fetchError) as! NSAsynchronousFetchResult
        }
```

This method is called on a view controller's didLoad method. The view controller is being managed by a UIPageViewController.

I cannot find a predicate that allows me to fetch the max date plus all related Journal entries. My current workaround is to fetch the latest, set a sort descriptor on the date and limit the results to 1 (receiving the max date). Then I run a second fetchRequest (from the beginning of the day until the end of the day). This is however only semi optimal and I'd like to know if someone knows a better way.

thanks for your help:

best,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

You can search for all entities that fall within two dates:

```
"date > %@ and date < %@"
```

Then use a NSCalendar to calculate the start date (i.e. today minus 1 day, 7 days, etc.).

Dates are stored as numbers so the search is very fast since it is a simple number comparison.

BTW, there is no reason to be using an async fetch to retrieve small amounts of data.  If you are really only getting 20 or less entities back, index the date property, put the date first in the predicate and the return will be fast.  Async fetches should only be used when you have a painful predicate that is searching against strings, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for pointing that out. I do not know the latest date though. Therefore I cannot parametrize it in the predicate without prior fetch. I thought about having a query that fetches the max date and then a subquery that takes care of the range. Got an idea?

Comment: Subquery can't feed off of a previous parameter in the same query.  So you would need to run two, get the max, calculate the beginning date and then run the final query.  Doable but slightly more time to process.